# Local notification data

Tags: ios, swift

Hello to all I'm stuck with one issue in my `iOS` app. I have searched over the internet and didn't find solution. Most of the solutions are using deprecated

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification)`

So scenario is following:

App schedules for each day 5 local notifications and that is okay and that works:

```
 var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.weekday = Date().dayNumberOfWeek()
    dateComponents.hour = hour
    dateComponents.minute = minute
    dateComponents.second = 5

    let notificationTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: notifcation, trigger: notificationTrigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

But my question is: **is it possible to find out when notification is fired regardless of app state and get data from that notification?**

Because time for each notification is retrieved from API I don't know when (hour and minute) notifications will be scheduled.

For example in Android I schedule notifications using `AlarmManager` API and than easly by extending `BroadcastReciver` I can fetch every fired notification and get data sent via `Intent`.

I need to find out when last (fifth) notification is fired for that day so I can preform some additional work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short no, it's not possible to be notified regardless of the app state.

If the app is running in foreground you can do this using [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate) methods, but if your app is not in foreground the app will know about the notification only if it's opened from the notification (swiping or tapping it).

Comment: Yeah after researching I was afraid of that. Thanks for response.